# Java: Permission Denied

Tags: java

I currently only have Sun JDK7 installed on my system in regards to Java.

When I try to run a program (the Unix Runescape Client), here is what comes up in my terminal:

> Trying to read
>   /home/ryanmcclure/Programs/runescape/share/settings.conf Error reading
>   settings.conf, using default value: 0 Error reading settings.conf,
>   using default value: default-java Error reading settings.conf, using
>   default value: 0 Error reading settings.conf, using default value:
>   runescape.prm
>
> Reading .prm file
>   /home/ryanmcclure/Programs/runescape/share/runescape.prm This is the
>   info i gathered from the runescape.prm file
>
> ## File Start
>
> -Djava.class.path=jagexappletviewer.jar  -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true 
>   -Dcom.jagex.config=http://www.runescape.com/k=3/l=$(Language:0)/jav_config.ws
>   -Xmx256m    -Xss1m
>        jagexappletviewer
>
> ## File End
>
> I will now parse the parameters! Checking your client language
>   setting(if any) Trying to read file
>   /home/ryanmcclure/jagexappletviewer.preferences
>
> Unable to read jagexappletviewer.preferences file, defaulting to
>   Language=0 (English). I will now parse the contents from the
>   jagexappletviewer.preferences file so it can be used. Stitching the
>   language setting to the final parameters.
>
> Final parameter string is:  jagexappletviewer.jar
>   -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dcom.jagex.config=http://www.runescape.com/k=3/l=0/jav_config.ws -Xmx256m  -Xss1m   jagexappletviewer
>
> Launching client using this java version: sh: java: Permission denied
>
> Launching the RuneScape Client using this command: cd
>   /home/ryanmcclure/Programs/runescape/bin && java -cp
>   jagexappletviewer.jar -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
>   -Dcom.jagex.config=http://www.runescape.com/k=3/l=0/jav_config.ws -Xmx256m  -Xss1m   jagexappletviewer /share
>
> Executing the RuneScape Client! You are now in the hands of Jagex.
>
> ## End Of Script
>   
>   ## Jagex client output will appear below here
>
> sh: java: Permission denied

What exactly does permission denied mean with Java? Please help!!!

Comment: have you tried starting it with `sudo` from the terminal?

Comment: Yes, and it still yields the same result. I'm at a loss right now

Comment: the JDK is the developer package, you might need additional software to run it. Look in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: facepalm.png  Wow, I'm an idiot. I'm removing JDK and am putting on JRE. Thank you...you saved me a world of confusion.

Comment: Still made no difference....Ugh, I really don't understand what could be wrong

Comment: What happens when you enter `java -version` in a terminal prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for it to work you need to be able to use the command "java"
could you try adding the binary directly to settings.conf?
you can find the binary on any linux distro by using the command

```
sudo find / -name "libjli.so" | sed "s/\/lib\/\(i386\|amd64\)\/jli\/libjli.so/\/bin\/java/g"
```

example for the settings in settings.conf can be found inside settings.conf.example

Comment: Hi @Hikariknight! You helped me with this a while back, but I never put this as the answer here on AU. :)